# Disable finger-swipe to minimize all tabs (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad, scrolling

I recently got a new Microsoft computer with Windows 10.

When I am using the touchpad to two-finger scroll, often all of my tabs will get minimized. After trying to re-create the problem, I figured out that when I use three fingers to scroll/swipe up, all tabs are minimized. This happens a lot accidentally, when I am using two fingers to scroll up but my hand touches the touchpad. I work with multiple monitors and always have many tabs open, so this is extremely frustrating.

Is there a way to turn this function off?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to "advanced gesture configuration" you can disable the three finger swipe down while keeping the other directional functions. It's not a perfect solution, because I still try and use that gesture when I'm in task view; however, it's better than the frustration of constantly minimizing tabs!

Also, I modified what the four-finger gestures do to compensate so I'm hoping I'll adjust sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I turned off three- and four-finger actions in the touchpad settings, and now this issue is resolved.

However, I liked being able to use three fingers to view my open apps, so if anyone has an alternative solution, that would be appreciated.